# Sending mail to cron connects to the wrong IP

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, cron

I'm running a server with Ubuntu 12.04 and we have some cron jobs that generate emails we want to receive. For handling that and other mails like that, I installed postfix and configured it to only listen on localhost since I don't want random people even trying to use it as SMTP relay.

I can successfully send mail by running:

```
mail pupeno@example.com
```

but when cron runs, it somehow tries to connect to the public IPs of the machine, which fails, because they are not bound by postfix:

```
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein cron[5503]: (postgres) RELOAD (crontabs/postgres)
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein CRON[12119]: (postgres) CMD (ls /)
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/pickup[11890]: 5F43928ACE: uid=109 from=<postgres>
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/cleanup[12068]: 5F43928ACE: message-id=<20120719092901.5F43928ACE@einstein.example.com>
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/qmgr[11891]: 5F43928ACE: from=<postgres@einstein.example.com>, size=647, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/smtp[12073]: connect to einstein.example.com[176.5.13.71]:25: Connection refused
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/smtp[12073]: connect to einstein.example.com[2a01:5800::96f1]:25: Connection refused
Jul 19 09:29:01 einstein postfix/smtp[12073]: 5F43928ACE: to=<postgres@einstein.example.com>, orig_to=<postgres>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to einstein.example.com[2a01:5800::96f1]:25: Connection refused)
```

I'm not even sure which program is connecting to the wrong IPs, so I don't know how to start solving it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My Postfix configuration is pretty standard:

```
# This file is managed by puppet, any manual changes will be lost.
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = einstein.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, cron does not connect anywhere to send email; it uses the sendmail(1) interface exposed by postfix and other MTAs.

As your log shows, postfix is trying to send the mail to itself via SMTP; this happens because postfix does not know it should handle mail for einstein.example.com.

Add the domain to mydestination and reload postfix.